# Creating a script that runs a simple command for all files in a directory

Tags: shell-script, wildcards, lynx

I need to use the text-based browser Lynx to dump 1000s of html files into text files, with the same filename.

For any given filename.html the command is

```
lynx filename.html --force-html --dump > filename.txt
```

The problem is I have tens of thousands of these files.

If I used `lynx *.html --force-html --dump *.html` I don't think each file will generate the text file with the same name.

Comment: You might use `html2text` instead of `lynx`  for such conversions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to execute `lynx` once per file, to produce separate output files. To do something over multiple files in sequence, use a [for loop](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Looping-Constructs). The [pattern](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Pattern-Matching) `*.html` matches all files in the current directory whose name ends with `.html`.

```
for x in *.html; do … done
```

In each run through the loop, the variable `x` designates the current file name. Use `"$x"` to refer to the file name (don't forget the double quotes or your script will break on some file names, e.g. containing spaces).

To build the `.txt` file name, remove the `.html` suffix from the value of `x` and add the `.txt` suffix. There is a [parameter expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) construct to get the value of a variable minus a suffix: `"${VARIABLE%SUFFIX}"`.

```
for x in *.html; do
  lynx --force-html --dump "$x" >"${x#.html}.txt"
done
```

If you want to act on HTML files in subdirectories as well, there are two possibilities. If your shell is bash, ksh or zsh, you can use the `**` pattern to recurse into subdirectories. In bash, this feature needs to be enabled with `shopt -s globstar` first; in ksh, with `set -o globstar`.

```
shopt -s globstar
for x in **/*.html; do
  lynx --force-html --dump "$x" >"${x#.html}.txt"
done
```

Alternatively, use the [`find`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/find) command. Since you need to do some manipulation on the file name, you need to make `find` run a shell.

```
find . -name '*.html' -exec sh -c '
  lynx --force-html --dump "$0" >"${0#.html}.txt"
' {} \;
```

`$0` is the first argument after `sh -c CODE`. It's a little faster to run the shell in batches, combining `find` (with `-exec … {} +`, instructing `find` to pass multiple file names to each single shell invocation) with a for loop. `for x do` means “iterate over the shell's command line arguments except `$0`”.

```
find . -name '*.html' -exec sh -c '
  for x; do lynx --force-html --dump "$x" >"${x#.html}.txt"; done
' _ {} +
```

Answer (score 1):

```
( set ./*.html; [ -f "$1" ] || exit
  printf 'eval "$L;shift" >"${1%%%.0s.*}.txt"\n' "$@" |
  L='    lynx "$1" --force-html --dump'  sh -eCs "$@"
) &
```

Answer (score -2):

```
for x in *.html;do
    lynx $x --force-html --dump >${x%%.html}.txt
done
```

Comment: Using a line-oriented tool like `grep` is not going to work on file names which don't have to be a single line (i.e. can have a newline embedded).

Comment: This got the job done!

Comment: Why on earth are you writing `*.html` in such a complicated, fragile way?

Comment: But it is not a good answer....